# How to add to value of custom (non-dependency) collection property value in XAML markup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have a simple object:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string MyValueProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and if I want to instantiate it in XAML and set the property (as below), this works:

```
<local:MyObject MyValueProperty="SomeValue" />
```

However, if my object has a **collection** property on it:

```
class MyObject
{
   public MyObject() { this.MyCollectionProperty = new List<string>(); }

   public IList<string> MyCollectionProperty { get; set; }
}
```

then I cannot work out how to add items to it through XAML.  What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
<local:MyObject>
    <local:MyObject.MyCollectionProperty>
         <sys:String>One</sys:String>
         <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
         <sys:String>etc</sys:String>
    </local:MyObject.MyCollectionProperty>
</local:MyObject>
```

I have tried this but I get a parse exception stating that I can't set `String` to a property of type `IList<string>`, and I realise I could probably work around this by adding an instantiation of a `List' to the markup, but I want to avoid this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out - the problem was because my property was defined as an `IList<T>` and so the XAML parser couldn't work out how to instantiate an appropriate instance (even though it already *had* an instance specified.

Changing the property declaration to `List<string>` get it working:

```
class MyObject
{
   public MyObject() { this.MyCollectionProperty = new List<string>(); }

   public List<string> MyCollectionProperty { get; set; }
}
```